Kdb fby select with multivariate function?
How do I do a select statement in kdb with fby on a function that takes more than one argument?
What I want is something like this:
t:([] price:1000?1f; sym:`AAPL; qty:3.0; open:0.20);
select from t where open<({exec x wavg y};qty;price) fby sym

without having to do
t:update avgPrice:qty wavg price by sym from t;
t:select from t where avgPrice>open;

EDIT: I found a way to do it without using flip
select from t where open<({[x] exec qty wavg price from x};([]qty;price)) fby sym


Small sample table with variety for testing:
q)t:([] price:15?10f; sym:15?`A`P`L; qty:15?3; open:15?10f);
q)t
price     sym qty open
---------------------------
3.614587  P   2   4.329653
8.378739  P   1   0.4506864
0.5421134 L   0   0.3795818
1.635727  A   0   9.475303
6.417787  L   1   0.7403326
6.655573  P   0   9.941467
8.064934  P   0   4.265147
4.316783  A   1   3.447288
9.054219  A   1   4.368897
3.741311  P   1   5.678812
7.319251  A   0   8.729202
4.999804  P   2   9.133432
7.846789  L   0   3.920599
6.721702  L   0   5.564439
7.074448  L   2   3.351027

Your version:
q)select from (update avgPrice:qty wavg price by sym from t) where avgPrice>open
price     sym qty open      avgPrice
------------------------------------
3.614587  P   2   4.329653  4.891472
8.378739  P   1   0.4506864 4.891472
0.5421134 L   0   0.3795818 6.855561
6.417787  L   1   0.7403326 6.855561
8.064934  P   0   4.265147  4.891472
4.316783  A   1   3.447288  6.685501
9.054219  A   1   4.368897  6.685501
7.846789  L   0   3.920599  6.855561
6.721702  L   0   5.564439  6.855561
7.074448  L   2   3.351027  6.855561

With fby as list of lists:
q)select from t where open<({x[;0] wavg x[;1]};flip (qty;price)) fby sym
price     sym qty open
---------------------------
3.614587  P   2   4.329653
8.378739  P   1   0.4506864
0.5421134 L   0   0.3795818
6.417787  L   1   0.7403326
8.064934  P   0   4.265147
4.316783  A   1   3.447288
9.054219  A   1   4.368897
7.846789  L   0   3.920599
6.721702  L   0   5.564439
7.074448  L   2   3.351027

Or sub tables:
q)select from t where open< ({exec qty wavg price from x};([]qty;price)) fby sym
price     sym qty open
---------------------------
3.614587  P   2   4.329653
8.378739  P   1   0.4506864
0.5421134 L   0   0.3795818
6.417787  L   1   0.7403326
8.064934  P   0   4.265147
4.316783  A   1   3.447288
9.054219  A   1   4.368897
7.846789  L   0   3.920599
6.721702  L   0   5.564439
7.074448  L   2   3.351027

Check results match:
q)a:delete avgPrice from select from (update avgPrice:qty wavg price by sym from t) where avgPrice>open
q)b:select from t where open<({x[;0] wavg x[;1]};flip (qty;price)) fby sym
q)a~b
1b
q)c:select from t where open< ({exec qty wavg price from x};([]qty;price)) fby sym
q)b~c
1b

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/fby/

I think you can do it without having to flip (qty;price) by wrapping your function if into something that takes a dictionary, like so ({exec qty wavg price from x};([]qty;price)) fby sym

Nice! Makes sense, have updated answer to include both. Docs show using tables to right of fby https://code.kx.com/q/ref/fby/  so showing to the left would be a good addition https://github.com/KxSystems/docs
